# Why couldn't she have told her minder about Clarke's note or simply called the police?

Tags: robert-a-heinlein, podkayne-of-mars

In *Podkayne of Mars*, we are informed that Venus is one of the safest places in the solar system as it is heavily policed. When Poddy finds that she is unable to reach Uncle Tom, the governor or his son, couldn't she simply have told her bodyguard about Clarke's note to her? Or called the cops who are very likely tearing the city apart trying to locate the VIP?

Are we expected to chalk this down to her naïveté?